# Entity-framework. How to report SQL constrain errors gracefully

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, validation, extjs, extjs4

I have a web-application: ExtJs frontend - EntityFramework + SQL Server as a backend. Let's take a look at one of the error scenarios:

- I have database constrains for username (name must be unique)
- I don't have any client side validation for that (should I? is there way to make such validation generic?)
- Server returns 500 error if I try to insert user with the same name.
- If I run it from the same machine IIS is on - I get full error message (basically SQL exception description with key violation etc), if I run it from other machine - I just get 500 error and no error message.

What's the best approach to handle this? I need to tell user in some human readable format about the error. I really don't want to turn on error messaging on the IIS because it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't have an error here, but a business rule violation.

I like to differentiate both of them, being the first some *unexpected* situation (like a database conection loss) and the later some scenario that you know its likely to happen.

For errors, I think the appropiate is to inform the user in a generic fashion (say, "an unexpected error has ocurred") because its something that the user can't correct nor need detailed information.

On the other hand, a business rule is something that the user might understand and can take action to correct (here, the user name constraint). So it should be notified to the user.

In projects I've worked on, we have a type of exception, `BusinessException`. We throw it with a message indicating what was the problem and it renders in a human readable format. We don't explicity try-catch this exceptions, but use a handler to manage them. If you're using MVC, there is an extension hook where you can do it.

For other types of exceptions, its a good practice to log the stacktrace somewhere (i.e. EventViewer), but not give the user the details.

In this case, I would do the following:

- Have a button *check names* to allow the user pre-validate the name.
- The place to validate the name, depends on where you want to have your application's business logic. On the DB, using stored procedures, is an approach, but if you're using EF, this means that you want to abstract from the data access. Instead, you can write this validation by yourself, using `LINQ` (something like `Context.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name)` and then check whether it returns null or some user. You might think this validation is not neccesary as you already have your DB constraint, but doing this way, the logic remains in your application's code.
- Capturing an exception from EF could be messy, because you need to check a SQL error code to determine whether it was a constraint violation or other error. And even if you determine that, you need to transform the message into a user friendly one.

I hope this helps you in your decision!

Comment: Thank you for such full answer. I will look into LINQ validation as you said. I totally agree with your 'Business-vs-Internal' errors point

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest you have validation prior to submitting to server on the client, by providing instant feedback to the user is a good experience.

Second, there are few options you can consider for the actual insert that I have use couple of:

1. Use store procedure that does the check and the insert and returns the new record as confirmation for successful insert, this is easy to do with transaction and handle all problems inside the store procedure, however now you have functionality sitting outside of your compiled code
2. In your insert procedure wrap a call to validate first in transaction and deal with it appropriately, provides you with compiled code and less complexity of external dependency like store procedure, however you have some limitations of type of transactional locks from that layer but doable
3. Try to insert and catch the exception, and deal with it appropriately, this is the least favorite of mine

I did not see you mentioning the update of the `UserName`, if you do allow this functionality you will have to validate before update as well due to the same problems present when you are doing insert.

Comment: I agree with client side validation. I really don't want to have hundreds of stored procedures and I was looking to somehow have a generic way within the EntityFramework to return an acceptable error. Do you know anything like this? I mean I don't event have access to CommitChanges function (which I use to do this) - EF transfers everything to InsertXXXX/UpdateXXX automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have any client side validation for that (should I? is there
>   way to make such validation generic?)

I would always do that. You may use jquery ajax to make a call to a server page and check the data there. This let the user to know that the user name is not available before even clicking on the submit button. That gives a better User Experience. this approach avoids another Server round trip (the normal form posting with all form data and then receiving an error)

> Server returns 500 error if I try to insert user with the same name.

Always catch Exceptions in your Code and **log it**. Show a friendly message to user about the error. Never show the Stacktrace of the Exception to the end user. If you are using ASP.NET, make use of the custom error page feature.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DbContext you can validate for uniquness by customizing the built-in validation. Take a look at this blogpost: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/27/ef-4-1-validation.aspx. Towards the end there is an example showing how to do that.